# How do I remove all newlines from a string in PowerShell?

Tags: parsing, powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0, comobject

This is the code I am using to parse my emails. If they match a specific date, I want to add them to a list of other emails, then make that into a flat file:

```
outfile = "C:\Temp\emails.csv"
$olFolderInbox = 6
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application"
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi")
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$msgs = $inbox.Folders.Item("root")
$list1 = @()
foreach($message in ($msgs.items))
{
    if($message.ReceivedTime -gt $(get-date).adddays(-14))
    {
        $list1 += "$($message.Subject);$($message.ReceivedTime);$($message.Body.Replace("`n",", "))"
    }
}
if(Test-Path $outfile)
{
    Remove-Item $outfile
    Add-Content $outfile $list1
}
else
{
    Add-Content $outfile $list1
}
```

The problem I run into is that the replace statement on `` $message.Body.Replace("`n",", ") `` doesn't actually remove newlines, and the file doesn't get created appropriately. Is there a way to confirm that the entire contents of the body portion become a single line?

I have confirmed that the `$message.body` object is a string, so I'm not certain why this is not working.

Comment: for html message, new line will be <br/> no ?

Comment: Have you tried using (...Replace("'r'n",", ")) (replace ' with backtick) ? If the Replace method doesn't work, try`$($message.Body -join ", ")` instead. That's the way to do it if it's actually a string-array `string[]`. I don't have outlook so I can check the object type myself, so putting this as a comment first :-)  Kayasax's is onto something too. You got 3 things to try now :)

Comment: You could also try PowerShell's split operator e.g. `$message.Body -split "'r?'n"` (substitute backtick for ').

Comment: I've attempted all of these individually, and together, and nothing seems to work. It may have something to do with the add-content cmdlet. When I write the file as a CSV, the file is only one line (but imports as multiple lines when imported into Excel); but if I write it as a txt, it has the line breaks in notepad as well... So the problem still isn't solved, but I might be getting closer.

Comment: @Graimer forgot to reference you in my previous comment

Answer (score 40):

Commenters point to the return `r and maybe that [special character](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847835.aspx) should be replaced separately. Guessing this could be done with the .replace() method and some regex. 
Or more simply (and clumsily I admit) with another variable before your $list1 += line, such as:

```
$bod = $message.body -replace "`n",", " -replace "`r",", "
```

Overkill, but here's a small example from scratch. I'm suggesting you add $y to make it easier to manipulate the message body.

```
$x = new-object -type psObject
$x | add-member memburr1 -membertype noteproperty -value "no trouble here"
$x | add-member memburr2 -membertype noteproperty -value "uh `n oh `r spaghettio"

$y = $x.memburr2 -replace "`n",", " -replace "`r",", "

$z = @()
$z += "$($x.memburr1);$y"
```

If this doesn't help, I'd be curious what appears immediately before and after a problematic line break in the output.

EDIT: Or use the .replace() method twice:

```
$x.memburr2.replace("`n",", ").replace("`r",", ")
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-8.0?

Comment: Generally speaking, sure, prefer `[System.Environment]::NewLine` but where `[system.Environment]::NewLine -eq "\`r\`n"` and text is sprinkled with `\`r` or `\`n` alone... YMMV?

Answer (score 19):

None of the above worked for me. What did work was:

```
$foo = [string]::join("",($foo.Split("`n")))
```